# Retrieving images from json server and display with relevant question

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am building a trivia app. initially I just implemented plain text Q&A trivia but now I also want to add images with questions. I am getting data from my local JSON server. I also shared one record of my JSON object at the end. Here is my API call, please help me how can retrieve images into my components.
here is code [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/trivia-er8s44?file=/src/API.ts). I have included the db.json file for reference but actually, I have a JSON server.

**API.ts**

```
import { shuffleArray } from "./utils"

export type Question = {
    category: string
    correct_answer: string
    difficulty: string
    incorrect_answers: string[]
    question: string
    type: string
}

export type QuestionsState = Question & { answers: string[] }

export enum Difficulty {
    EASY = "easy",
    MEDIUM = "medium",
    HARD = "hard",
}

export const fetchQuizQuestions = async (amount: number, difficulty: Difficulty): Promise<QuestionsState[]> => {
    const endpoint = `http://localhost:3000/results`;
    const data = await (await fetch(endpoint)).json();
    console.log('**********', data)
    return data.map((question: Question) => ({
        ...question,
        answers: shuffleArray([...question.incorrect_answers, question.correct_answer]),
    }))
};
```

and **QuestionCard.jsx**

```
type Props = {
    question: string;
    answers: string[];
    callback: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
    userAnswer: AnswerObject | undefined;
    questionNr: number;
    totalQuestions: number;

}

export const QuestionCard: React.FC<Props> = ({ question, answers, callback, userAnswer, questionNr, totalQuestions }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p className='number'>
                Question: {questionNr} / {totalQuestions}
            </p>
            <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: question }} />
            <div>
                {answers.map(answer => (
                    <div >
                        <button disabled={userAnswer ? true : false} value={answer} onClick={callback}>
                            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: answer }} />
                        </button>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**db.json** few records are

```
  {
            "category": "driving",
            "type": "multiple",
            "difficulty": "hard",
            "question": "what is the shape of give-way sign?",
            "image-url": "https://cdn-01.media-brady.com/store/stnl/media/catalog/product/d/m/dmeu_y4142995_01_std.lang.all.gif",
            "correct_answer": "triangle",
            "incorrect_answers": [
                "rounded",
                "oval",
                "rectengle"
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have `image-url` in your api response so you can get it with new `props` like `questionImage` or you can convert your `question props` type to object and you can get from there. Then you just need to put in `src` of `img`

```
export const QuestionCard: React.FC<Props> = ({ question, answers, callback, userAnswer, questionNr, totalQuestions, questionImage }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p className='number'>
                Question: {questionNr} / {totalQuestions}
            </p>
            <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: question}} />
            <img src={quesionImage} alt={"questionImage"}/>
            <div>
                {answers.map(answer => (
                    <div >
                        <button disabled={userAnswer ? true : false} value={answer} onClick={callback}>
                            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: answer }} />
                        </button>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I tried but cannot achieve it. Here is the sandbox link. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/trivia-er8s44?file=/src/API.ts
I made a db.json file of the API server. can you please help to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> I hope this solution will work for you. first add imageUrl:string

```
export type Question = {
    category: string
    correct_answer: string
    difficulty: string
    incorrect_answers: string[]
    question: string
    imageUrl: string
    type: string
}
```

> then add qImage as I did

```
type Props = {
    question: string;
    qImage?: string;
    answers: string[];
    callback: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
    userAnswer: AnswerObject | undefined;
    questionNr: number;
    totalQuestions: number;

}

export const QuestionCard: React.FC<Props> = ({
    question,
    qImage,
    answers,
    callback,
    userAnswer,
    questionNr,
    totalQuestions }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p className='number'>
                Question: {questionNr} / {totalQuestions}
            </p>
            <img src={qImage} alt="icons" />
            <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: question }} />
            <div>
                {answers.map(answer => (
                    <div >
                        <button disabled={userAnswer ? true : false} value={answer} onClick={callback}>
                            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: answer }} />
                        </button>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

> and finally use qIamge in your app like this

```
{!loading && !gameOver && (
    <QuestionCard
      question={questions[number].question}
      qImage={questions[number].imageUrl}
      answers={questions[number].answers}
      callback={CheckAnswer}
      userAnswer={userAnswers ? userAnswers[number] : undefined}
      questionNr={number + 1}
      totalQuestions={TOTAL_QUESTION}
    />
  )}
```

Comment: Super, Thank you so much. this solution is working as I need